# Issues with jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I wrote the following code that uses jQuery UI's autocomplete method on a text box.

```
$(function() {
    $('#project').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){response(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects))},
            minLength: 0,
            messages: {noResults: '', results: function(){}},
            autoFocus: true
        }).on('focus', function(event) { //Display the suggestions list on focus
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });
})
```

I'm facing the following issues:

1. While clicking on a text field does show the corresponding list of suggestions, the autoFocus doesn't work. I want the first value in the list to be highlighted. But this is all I get:[image]
2. On mouse-over, the list elements get highlighted, like so:

   [image]

   I use the following styling to accomplish this:

   ```
   .ui-autocomplete a:hover {background-color: #C1CDCD;cursor:default}
   ```

   But, when I use the up/down arrows to navigate the list, the
   corresponding value shows in the text field but the element in the
   list doesn't get highlighted.

How do I resolve these issues?

Here's the [JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/HaZqz/).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle?  It seems like there are 2 simple css rules that would accomplish this.

Comment: @Rooster: Just added the fiddle to the question

Comment: You are missing the jquery-ui autocomplete css. You don't have to style it yourself

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez: Oh didn't know about that. Will look at it

Comment: @raul Add the css and delete yours, then the problem is solved, I tested it now

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/tags/1.8.22/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?spec=svn4136&r=4136)? But this only creates a bland list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by utilizing the open and focus methods, then turning the autofocus off so it doesn't unhighlight the first item.  I also utilized a class called first open to allow the first item to be highlighted again if it initially loses focus.

code:

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HaZqz/1/)

codez:

```
projects = {Apple: "fruit",Apostle: "Saint"};
$(function () {
    $('#project').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            response(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(projects));
        },
        minLength: 0,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {}
        },
        //autoFocus: true,
        open: function( event, ui ) {
                $('.ui-autocomplete > li:first-child a').addClass('ui-state-focus first_open');
        },
        focus: function( event, ui ) {            
            if(ui.item.value != $('.ui-state-focus').text()){
                $('.first_open').removeClass('ui-state-focus first_open');
            }

       },    
    }).on('focus', function (event) { //Display the suggestions list on focus   
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");

    });
});
```

Comment: Works like magic! although I don't understand much of the new code

Comment: so when the suggestions open, the first item in the list get the class `first_open` as well as `ui-state-focus` which is what the autosuggest uses to highlight.  Then an item is focused, the `ui-state-focus` class needs to be removed from the first item, but only the first time focus is changed.  thats whats going on in those 2 methods.